# Restructured text splits paragraph between pages and adds erroneous list bullet

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

So my issue is that I am generating a document for one of our products and this item is split between two pages and it adds an extra bullet (as circled below). How can I remove this wrong bullet or simply force the list item to the next page?

Syntax of split line

```
* I am a very long statement and I create a bullet when I continue on to the next line. Why does this happen? I am using rst2pdf to generate this document. Please send help. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. *(XXXXXX-40A, August 2019)* (`CN-XXXXX <https://www.jira.com/browse/CN-XXXXX>`_)
```

Versions

```
pytest = "^5.0"
pylama = "^7.6"
pylint = "^2.2"
pytest-cov = "^2.6"
black = "18.9b0"
sphinx = "^2.0"
docutils = "0.16"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rst2pdf uses the [raw directive](http://rst2pdf.ralsina.me/handbook.html#raw-directive) to insert manual pagebreaks:

```
One page

.. raw:: pdf

    PageBreak

Another page
```

Or switch to a different PDF engine (I tried your reST markdown via [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) - which uses texlive - and the widow/orphan pagination looks fine).

---

Edit:

I installed [rst2pdf v0.97](https://rst2pdf.org/) and out-of-the-box the PDF also looks fine.

[image]

So guess your Sphinx project `conf.py` (or the rst2pdf stylesheets chosen) must be customized.  Try a different stylesheet to see if problem persists, e.g.

```
pdf_stylesheets = ['autumn','kerning','a4-landscape']
```

Comment: I think you're a life saver. I am going to try this (pandoc) tomorrow. I want it to be automatic.

Comment: I'm having trouble. Can you please share the exact command you used with pandoc?

Comment: pandoc was just a quick sanity check (copy the line "I am a very long statement..." into a file `dummy.rst`, pad extra bulletpoints to make it spill across two pages, then `pandoc -o results.pdf dummy.rst`). Sphinx normally uses LaTeX - does `make latexpdf` work for you?